# Can you assign multiple drivers to one bone?

Tags: bones, drivers

Can you assign multiple drivers to one bone? Is that possible?

Comment: Why would you write "The question is in the title. Is it possible?" Why not just rewrite your question? (like I did when I edited your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A driver is used to calculate a single value. Only one driver can be assigned to calculate a specific value.

So yes a bone can have several drivers, one for it's x-location, one for it's y-location, one for it's x-rotation and so on.

If you need to use more complex logic to calculate the value, you can define a python function within the [driver namespace](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html#driver-namespace).

```
import bpy

def driver_func(val):
    return val * val    # return val squared

# add function to driver_namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['driver_func'] = driver_func
```